# call javascript function from AJAX php file isn't working

Tags: php, ajax

SOLVED! I used only javascript to the task. Now it reads the text from the php and use the coordinates.

```
        var texto = HttpReq.responseText;
        var lats,lons;
        var pos = texto.search(' ');
        lats = texto.substring(0,pos-1);
        lons = texto.substring(pos+1);
```

Thank you all! You are wonderful!

---

My site has a main page, where after the user selects a city, I wanna show it on a google map. The coordinates of the cities are in a table, so I'm using php in a separate .php file, accessed through AJAX. In the separate .php, I want to call a JS function from the main page to add the point to the map (the JS map object was on the main page, I also tried to put all the JS in a .js file, but the function still isn't called at all (I'm using FireBug to breakpoint it, but the function is never called).

The result from AJAX's GET is this:

```
Latitude: -21.15361<BR>Longitude: -41.567501<BR><script src="functions.js" type="text/javascript">addPoint(-21.15361,-41.567501);</script>
```

The Latitude and Longitude appears on screen, but the method addPoint ain't called. Am I missing something stupid here? Thanks in advance.

-- EDIT --
OK, here's what I'm trying to do (that's inside getcoords.php, the file called thru ajax):

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("select id_mun,lat,lon from municipio where id_mun = '".$_GET['mun']."'");
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    echo '<script src="functions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>';
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)) {
        echo "Latitude: $row[1]<BR>";
        echo "Longitude: $row[2]<BR>";
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
        echo 'alert("testando");';
        echo "addPoint($row[1],$row[2]);";
        echo "</script>";
    }
}
```

and the result that goes to the innerHtml from my div (and is not executed):

```
<script src="functions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>Latitude: -15.779722<BR>Longitude: -47.929722<BR><script type="text/javascript">alert("testando");addPoint(-15.779722,-47.929722);</script>
```

Thanks again.

Comment: can you show us your addPoint function? Kinda difficult to see the problem with any real code.

Comment: There's nothing really special with it. I've put an 'alert' inside it, and it doesn't show. Even the 'alert' in the script that calls this function ain't called either.
function addPoint(lat,lon) {
    var point = new GLatLng(lat,lon);
    map.addOverlay(new GMarker(point));
}

Answer (score 1):

Any code inside `<script></script>` will not be executed if the `src` attribute is present. You'll need two script blocks instead of one:

```
<script src="functions.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script type="text/javascript">addPoint(-21.15361,-41.567501);</script>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, but it won't work either. I'm showing more code above.

Answer (score 0):

Stuff in <script> is only executed while page is loading. You need to call the code from within your AJAX response handler, not just inject it into the page.

Comment: That means I need to use jQuery for that? Or is there any other possibility? And what about the other <script>, why the 'alert' ain't working?

Comment: No need to use jQuery, but it would make it easier. If I were you, I would wrap the code in a function, add it to page source and then call it at the end of AJAX response handler.

Comment: Milan, there is a tradeoff between doing it in a way that will run faster and run in most computers, versus doing it easier. I usually prefer Delphi (now I'm giving Lazarus a try) and C++ than anything on rails. In Delphi I rather write my own solutions than download "components". I agree with mr. micosyen that simplicity is a rule -- though I'm not down to assembler yet... :) I'll look at jQuery. And that's a good idea. Will try it now. Thank you.